# How to read pre-recorded video asset frame by frame from disk on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, avfoundation, video-processing

I'm trying to process recorded video on IOS device using `AVAssetReader` to capture each frame from it.
I've faced an issue that the `buffer` returned from `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()` method cannot be converted to `CVImageBuffer` which I need to treat it as a frame. The method returns `nil`.

I suppose that I might be wrong with objects initialization, please consider the code. Or if you know some other way to treat a video from disk as a stream of frames, please share this idea.

```
// Variables out of this snippet 
// videoURL = <some video on disk path>
// context = CIContext()

let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL! as URL , options: nil)
guard let assetReader = try? AVAssetReader(asset: asset) else { return }
let videoTracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)
let videoOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTracks[0], outputSettings: nil)

guard assetReader.canAdd(videoOutput) else { return }
assetReader.add(videoOutput)
assetReader.startReading()
guard let sampleBuffer = videoOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() else {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
    // fall down here
    // won't convert sampleBuffer to CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer
    return
}
let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return }
```

I've tried the code in the snippet with different amendments:

1. `AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput` instead `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` this fails on `.startReading()`
2. `AVOutputSettingsAssistant(preset: AVOutputSettingsPreset.preset1920x1080)?.videoSettings` to get options to pass in `outputSettings` instead of `nil`. This errors in runtime complaining about unsupported options

Answer (score 1):

As I thought the problem was in `outputSettings`

I adopted Objective-C parameters from the WWDC session 415 "Working with media in AVFoundation" to Swift. And that helped to get sample buffer convertible to image object

```
let videoOptions = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange,
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 640,
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 480,
]
let videoOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTracks[0], outputSettings: videoOptions)
```